# iOS 12 Password Autofill with Local HTML file

Tags: ios, webview, ios12

I am currently testing iOS 12's new Password Autofill feature. The WWDC talk says it does support WKWebview. However I cannot get the keyboard to suggest any creds.

The sample project contains half a webview with 2 input fields and half contains 2 native text fields.

I added the textfields as the control. They DO populate creds and Password autofill works as expected.

On the web view it just shows the Passwords with key icon.

Here is my html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myform">
        <div align="center">
            <br><br>
             <input id="user-text-field" type="email" autocomplete="username"/>
             <input id="password-text-field" type="password" autocomplete="current-password"/>
                <br><br>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Has anyone else gotten it to work with local html files? I did file a radar but they said they can not reproduce which is impossible. The sample app shows it simple does not work.

My Config
Xcode b4/b5
iOS 12 b4/b5
iPhone X